# How to select queries under conditions with queries on same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tried this

```
select case when exists (select * from rnr.company_faqs fo where fo.mp_company_uid=734) 
      then select * from rnr.company_faqs fo where fo.mp_company_uid=734
      else select * from rnr.faq_master
      end
```

I am getting error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2:           then select * from rnr.company_faqs fo where fo.mp...
                       ^
```

********** Error **********

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 105
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your `SELECT` with open and close parentheses `()`:

```
select
case 
    when exists (select * from rnr.company_faqs fo where fo.mp_company_uid=734) then
        (select * from rnr.company_faqs fo where fo.mp_company_uid = 734)
    else
        (select * from rnr.faq_master)
end
```

When you try to write it manually, you will have a script like this:

```
select select * from rnr.company_faqs fo where fo.mp_company_uid = 734
```

which will really give you an error.

But if you wrap it with `()`:

```
select (select * from rnr.company_faqs fo where fo.mp_company_uid = 734)
```

It will make the script correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you can use CASE WHEN only with scalar data but your `SELECT *` return row sets. Try this using UNION:

```
  select * from rnr.company_faqs fo where fo.mp_company_uid=734
  UNION ALL
  select * from rnr.faq_master 
       WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * 
                          from rnr.company_faqs fo 
                         where fo.mp_company_uid=734)
```

Comment: @Zafta Did you try to run it ? Does it show any error ?

Answer (score -1):

IF The resultset columns  from table rnr.company_faqs  and rnr.faq_master are same.

You should try "UNION" to select the data

```
Select * from (
     select * from rnr.company_faqs fo where fo.mp_company_uid=734
     UNION
     select * from rnr.faq_master
) a;
```

if rnr.company_faqs have result set it will give one row else return null;

The UNION result set will be intersection.

You can modify the Query to get desired result-set.

Hope it helps!